# Highcharts - Issue with showing and hiding plot lines and bands on legendItemClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart on which I have several x axis plotLines and plotBands.
I have a function, which on legendItemClick, will show/hide the plotLines and Bands.
(it is a histogram with normal curve overlaid and stdev levels marked)

The chart and code can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/FnhRV/

```
function toggleBands(chart) {
  $.each(chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands, function(index,el){
    if(el.svgElem != undefined) {
      el.svgElem[ el.visible ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
      el.visible = !el.visible;
    }
  });
}
```

The problem:  when other series are shown or hidden, and the x axis scales accordingly, if any of the plot lines or bands fall off the scale, the behavior starts getting hinky.

In the example posted, if you hide the normal curve series, the outermost plotlines will be outside the bounds of the x axis.
Once that happens, those two lines will reappear every time you hide them, and clicking on the various legend items will cause various states of hidden/visible that shouldn't be.

IF the series are such that the axis always remains wide enough for the plotlines, this error DOES NOT happen, and the showing and hiding will happily occur as intended.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and/or provide a solution?
thanks in advance

Jamie

{{edit:
setting a min and max to match the curve value will not help the situation in this case, as the desired usability is that the user can hide the curve and see the chart scaled to the histogram data.

Comment: Anyone...?

Any tips on how to overcome this issue at all?

Comment: Does this mean there is no solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PlotLines` and `plotBands` are coming back, because when axis is displayed back again it should also render all plotLines and plotBands. Then you can't control in easy way plotLines and plotBands. How to resolve that? Instead of hiding/showing SVG element, remove plotLines/plotBands or add them as required. Here is solution for you: http://jsfiddle.net/FnhRV/19/

Comment: works well! in addition to that, need to take care of the yAxis destroy and update as well, otherwise it may not works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set min/max values.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/FnhRV/

```
    min:-3,
    max:3,
    showEmpty: true,
```

Comment: That is the first option that I considered, but I really want to be able to have the x axis scale to the histogram data if I hide the curve.  In the given example, the difference in scaling is minimal, but in many cases the difference is quite large.

In those cases, not allowing the user to hide the curve and view the columns independently will be a significant detriment to usability.

Comment: anyone have any tips?  I am stuck, and need to get this functioning properly some how...